# validateForm function

Tags: javascript, function

The following function uses the JavaScript `every` method to check the validity of all the fields in a form:

```
// Input:

validatingFields: [{
  name: 'Name',
  type: 'text',
   validation: {
     isRequired: true,
     pattern: util.regex().email,
     minLength: 2
     maxLength: 4
   }
}]

// Function:

validateForm () {
  this.isValid = this.validatingFields.every(field => {
    const isRequired = field.validation.isRequired
    const maxLength = field.validation.maxLength
    const minLength = field.validation.minLength
    const pattern = field.validation.pattern
    const match = field.validation.match
    if (match) {
      const matchRegex = this.convertToRegex(match)
      return matchRegex.test(field.value)
    }
    if (pattern) {
      return pattern.test(field.value)
    }
    if (minLength) {
      return field.value.length >= minLength
    }
    if (maxLength) return field.value.length <= maxLength
    if (isRequired) return field.value
    return true
  })
}
```

The problem is, the function returns inside every `if` statement. So, for example, when `minLength` is present, `maxLength` is never checked.

How to modify the function so it validates every condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to store the validity in a variable and return it in the end:

```
validateForm () {
    this.isValid = this.validatingFields.every(field => {
        const isRequired = field.validation.isRequired
        const maxLength = field.validation.maxLength
        const minLength = field.validation.minLength
        const pattern = field.validation.pattern
        const match = field.validation.match

        var tValid = true;

        if (match) {
            const matchRegex = this.convertToRegex(match)
            tValid = matchRegex.test(field.value)
        }

        if (tValid && pattern){
            tValid = pattern.test(field.value)
        }

        if (tValid && minLength) {
            tValid = field.value.length >= minLength
        }

        if (tValid && maxLength) tValid = field.value.length <= maxLength
        if (tValid && isRequired) tValid = !!field.value

        return tValid
    })
}
```

Another way would be to chain the arguments:

```
validateForm () {
    this.isValid = this.validatingFields.every(field => {
        //..

        return
            (
                (pattern ? pattern.test(field.value) : true) &&
                (minLength ? field.value.length >= minLength : true) &&
                (maxLength ? field.value.length <= maxLength : true) &&
                (isRequired ? !!field.value : true)
            )
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this way, `if (tValid && isRequired) tValid = field.value` sets `tValid` to `true` regardless what happens with the previous conditions.

Comment: @alex: How so? It only gets checked if tValid is true in the first place.

Comment: `tValid` can become `false` in the previous conditions, but it finally becomes `true` in `if (tValid && isRequired) tValid = !!field.value` because `isRequired` is set to `true`.

Comment: @alex: Like I wrote, if tValid is false, this one does not get executed. So I do not comprehend your comment I am afraid :(

Comment: Never mind, I made the mistake of not copy-pasting your code, haha. Thanks!

Comment: @alex: You are welcome. Please make sure to accept the answer of your choice if the issued has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

What about declaring an integer i=0 before you start the if statement, then inside every if condition, check if its true then i++ at the end check if i ==5 then return true (5 successful if conditions) else return false

```
validateForm () {
this.isValid = this.validatingFields.every(field => {
const isRequired = field.validation.isRequired
const maxLength = field.validation.maxLength
const minLength = field.validation.minLength
const pattern = field.validation.pattern
const match = field.validation.match

int i=0;
if (match) {
  const matchRegex = this.convertToRegex(match)
  if(matchRegex.test(field.value) == true)
    i++;
}
if (pattern) {
  if(pattern.test(field.value) ==true)
     i++;
}
if (minLength) {
  if(field.value.length >= minLength)
     i++;
}
if (maxLength) 
   if(field.value.length <= maxLength)
     i++;

if (isRequired) r
   if(field.value == true)
     i++;

if(i == 5)
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

})
}

Comment: @Junior John: I would inverse your logic. Count all the errors instead, so one could check i == 0 in the end. Else one is bound to the amount of arguments.

Comment: i=0;
i+=~~matchRegex.test(field.value);
i+=~~pattern.test(field.value);
i+=~~(field.value.length >= minLength);
i+=~~(field.value.length <= maxLength);
i+=~~!!field.value == true;

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is what I did changes in your code:

```
validateForm () {
this.isValid = this.validatingFields.every(field => {
const isRequired = field.validation.isRequired
const maxLength = field.validation.maxLength
const minLength = field.validation.minLength
const pattern = field.validation.pattern
const match = field.validation.match
int count =0;
if (match) {
  const matchRegex = this.convertToRegex(match)
  count = matchRegex.test(field.value) ? count++ : count;
}
if (pattern) {
  count = pattern.test(field.value) ? count++ : count;
}
if (minLength) {
  count = (field.value.length >= minLength) ? count++ : count;
}
if (maxLength) count = (field.value.length <= maxLength) ? count++ : count;
if (isRequired) count = (field.value) > count++ : count;
return (count == 5) ? true : false;
})
}
```

As your code seems to have 5 validations, we can place a **count** for this and at the end if **count is equals to  5** we return true else false.